# "Invalid floating point operation" while creating a new form

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am getting an error "Invalid floating point operation" while creating a new form as below:

```
procedure TfrmForm1.actMyProcedureExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyForm2 : TfrmForm2;
begin
  MyForm2 := TfrmForm2.Create(Self);  //Getting error while executing this statement. I put a breakpoint on Create event of TForm2 form, but before that I am getting this error and breakpoint never comes on OnCreate event of TForm2 form.

end;
```

Comment: The answer is found in the implementation of TfrmForm2, pas and dfm. Only you can see that.

Comment: My comment in the code : I put a break-point on Create event of TForm2 form, but before that I am getting this error and break-point never comes on OnCreate event of TForm2 form.

Comment: Ok, if you don't want to expand the question, I've given an answer at the same level of detail as the question. Over to you to do the rest of the investigation.

Comment: Try and enable debug DCU's and you will see what David is telling you.

Answer (score 1):

The error is raised during execution of the constructor of `TfrmForm2`. The error is raised before your `OnCreate` event is executed.

The most likely explanation therefore is that the exception is raised during creation and property setting of the controls specified in the dfm file.

Another possibility, I suppose, is that you have added a constructor for the class and code in there raises the exception. That I suspect is less likely.

Debug this by enabling debug DCUs and then looking at the call stack when the exception is raised. This should give you a pointer to which part of construction is failing. Once you've identified the point of failure you can then attempt to solve the problem.

Finally, in the absence of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question, this is the type of answer you can expect. Broad and general.